# Using RasterCalculator in ArcGIS Pro ModelBuilder gives ERROR 000539

Tags: modelbuilder, arcgis-pro, raster-calculator, error-000732, error-000539

As part of a larger model for iterating lake bathymetry interpolations, I'm essentially trying to establish the lake altitude as a new base level (Z=0) for the DEM surrounding the lake. (picture below is just one part of the full model)

[image: The relevant model part with the following step in grey]

My latest atempt at a workaround is trying to use RasterCalculator to "simply" subtract the aproximate lake altitude I've extracted from the local lake DEM (through Zonal statistics) using the equation pictured below. Where the "Value" variable is set as string.

[image: Rastercalculator equation]

However, when running it I get following error msg:

```
ERROR 000539: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<expression>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 5, in rcexec
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 4341, in Minus
    in_raster_or_constant2)
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Utils.py", line 53, in swapper
    result = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 4338, in Wrapper
    ["Minus", in_raster_or_constant1, in_raster_or_constant2])
RuntimeError: ERROR 000732: Input Raster: Dataset 138.119995117 does not exist or is not supported
 Failed to execute (Raster Calculator).
```

I feel like there's probably a simple solution to this, but I really don't know where to go from here. From trying to look at the Functions code, I think it has to do with RasterCalculator not beeing able to use my "Value" variable. I've dabbled a bit with Python, but not to the extent to where I could solve this by just writing my own piece of code.

Comment: Try using the minus tool instead of the raster calculator tool.

Comment: There's always a simpler solution. This worked great and eliminated one step. Perfect!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What is happening** is that the Raster Calculator is trying to subtract one complete raster from another. It believes you have supplied a new raster named "%Value%" which evaluates to a raster named 138.1199...  The calculator cannot find that raster in the default workspace location and errors.

If you want to go down this path, use the [`Create Constant Raster`](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/create-constant-raster.htm) function, supply it with an `output name`, the `constant value` you computed, `cell-size` and `extents` to match your surrounding raster. Once that raster is produced, the above `Raster Calculator` will do the subtraction for you. -- remember you have to supply the new raster name to the Raster Calculator as the subtrahend (raster being subtracted).